# Reading a text file into a character array in c

Tags: c, arrays, csv, char, text-files

I'm writing a program that uses the command-line arguments to receive the name of a text file from the user. The text file is a very simple CSV file such as:

```
Bob's experiment,12,14,15,16
Mary's experiment,16,15,18
```

I just want it to print the experiment name then the average of all the numerical values. I'm attempting to do this by putting all the numbers and commas into a char array and I don't know where I've gone wrong.

This is what I have:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
    if(argc == 2) {
            FILE *txt_file;
            txt_file=fopen(argv[1], "rt");
            char str[4096];

            if(!txt_file) {
                    printf("File does not exist.\n");
                    return 1;
            }

            while(!feof(txt_file)){
                    char s;
                    s = fgetc(txt_file);

                    //prints experiment name
                    if(s != ',' && (!isdigit(s))) {
                            printf("%c", s);
                    }

                    if(isdigit(s) || s == ',') {
                            fgets(str, 4096, txt_file);
                    }
               }
             fclose(txt_file);
             return 0;
         }
```

Comment: What's not working ? What's your actual question?

Comment: You might find the strchr and atoi functions function useful. Use atoi to find the value of the first number in str and then use a loop with strchr to find the next comma.

Comment: possible duplicate of [calculating average of values from a CSV file in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26877131/calculating-average-of-values-from-a-csv-file-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this, but you should tailor your input routine to the type of data you are reading from your file. Here you are reading **lines** of data, so you should focus on **line-oriented** input routines (`fgets`, `getline`, or a shoehorned `scanf`). The basic approach is to read a line of input from your file into a `buffer` and then parse the line as needed. You can do this dynamically allocating all storage needed, or you can define a maximum value that should be large enough to handle your data.

Next you will need to parse the `buffer` read from the file to get the `experiment name` and each of the `values` associated so that an `average` can be calculated. Again, there are many ways to do this, but `strtol` is tailor made for this purpose. It takes a `pointer` to the string to convert and returns an `endptr` to the next character that is not a number. This allows you to read a values and set `pointer = endptr+1` which sets you up to read your next number.

I have put these pieces together in the example below. It is commented to help you follow along. Drop a comment if you have any additional questions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXEXPS 256

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input. Usage %s <filename>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    char *line = NULL;              /* line read from file (getline allocates if NULL)  */
    size_t n = 0;                   /* number of characters to read (0 - no limit)      */
    ssize_t nchr = 0;               /* number of characters actually read by getline    */
    char *p = NULL;                 /* pointer to use parsing values from line          */
    char *lnp = NULL;               /* second pointer to use parsing values from line   */
    char *expname[MAXEXPS] = {0};   /* array of MAXEXPS pointers for experiment names   */
    int expavg[MAXEXPS] = {0};      /* array of MAXEXPS ints to hold averages           */
    int val = 0;                    /* val returned by each call to strtol              */
    int eidx = 0;                   /* experiment index                                 */
    int idx = 0;                    /* value index                                      */

    FILE *txt_file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!txt_file) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: unable to open file '%s'\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    while ((nchr = getline (&line, &n, txt_file)) != -1)    /* read each line in file   */
    {
        p = strchr (line, ',');                             /* find first ','           */
        *p = 0;                                             /* set it to null (zero)    */
        expname[eidx] = strdup (line);    /* copy exp name to array (strdup allocates)  */
        lnp = ++p;                                          /* set lnp to next char     */
        int sum = 0;                                        /* reset sum to 0           */
        idx = 0;                                            /* reset idx to 0           */
        while ((val = (int)strtol (lnp, &p, 10)) != 0 && lnp != p) /* read next number  */
        {
            sum += val;                                     /* add val to sum           */
            lnp = ++p;                                      /* set lnp to next char     */
            idx++;                                          /* inc idx                  */ 
        }
        expavg[eidx++] = (idx > 0) ? sum / idx : 0;         /* calc avg for experiment  */
    }

    fclose (txt_file);

    /* print the averages of experiments */
    n = 0;
    printf ("\n  Experiment          Avg\n");
    printf ("  -----------------------\n");
    while (expname[n])
    {
        printf ("  %-18s  %d\n", expname[n], expavg[n]);
        n++;
    }
    printf ("\n");

    /* free all allocated memory        */
    n = 0;
    if (line)
        free (line);
    while (expname[n])
        free (expname[n++]);

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/csvavgfixed dat/csvavg.dat

  Experiment          Avg
  -----------------------
  Bob's experiment    14
  Mary's experiment   16
```

**memory allocation/free summary:**

```
==22148== HEAP SUMMARY:
==22148==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22148==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 723 bytes allocated
==22148==
==22148== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==22148==
==22148== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==22148== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this would do what you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int n = 0, count = 0, t = 0;
    if(argc == 2) {
            FILE *txt_file;
            txt_file=fopen(argv[1], "rt");
            char str[4096];

            if(!txt_file) {
                    printf("File does not exist.\n");
                    return 1;
            }

            while(!feof(txt_file)){
                    char s;

                    s = fgetc(txt_file);

                    //prints experiment name
                    if(s != ',' && (!isdigit(s))) {
                            if(n!=0) {
                              printf("%d\n", n / count);
                              n = 0;
                              count = 0;
                            }
                            printf("%c", s); 
                    }

                    if(s == ',') {
                            fscanf(txt_file, "%d", &t);
                            n+=t;
                            count++;
                    }
               }
             printf("%d\n", n / count);
             fclose(txt_file);
             return 0;
         }
}
```

Comment: There should not be any space between commas and numbers.

Comment: Check where you are dividing by `count`. What happens when `count = 0`?